# Parse and transform XML with missing elements into table structure

Tags: xml, r, dataframe, data.table, reshape

I'm trying to parse an XML file.  A simplified version of it looks like this:

```
x <- '<grandparent><parent><child1>ABC123</child1><child2>1381956044</child2></parent><parent><child2>1397527137</child2></parent><parent><child3>4675</child3></parent><parent><child1>DEF456</child1><child3>3735</child3></parent><parent><child1/><child3>3735</child3></parent></grandparent>'

library(XML)
xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(x))
## <grandparent>
##   <parent>
##     <child1>ABC123</child1>
##     <child2>1381956044</child2>
##   </parent>
##   <parent>
##     <child2>1397527137</child2>
##   </parent>
##   <parent>
##     <child3>4675</child3>
##   </parent>
##   <parent>
##     <child1>DEF456</child1>
##     <child3>3735</child3>
##   </parent>
##   <parent>
##     <child1/>
##     <child3>3735</child3>
##   </parent>
## </grandparent>
```

I'd like to transform the XML into a data.frame / data.table that looks like this:

```
parent <- data.frame(child1=c("ABC123",NA,NA,"DEF456",NA), child2=c(1381956044, 1397527137, rep(NA, 3)), child3=c(rep(NA, 2), 4675, 3735, 3735))
parent
##   child1     child2 child3
## 1 ABC123 1381956044     NA
## 2   <NA> 1397527137     NA
## 3   <NA>         NA   4675
## 4 DEF456         NA   3735
## 5   <NA>         NA   3735
```

If each parent node always contained all of the possible elements ("child1", "child2", "child3", etc.), I could use `xmlToList` and `unlist` to flatten it, and then `dcast` to put it into a table.  But the XML often has missing child elements.  Here is an attempt with incorrect output:

```
library(data.table)

## Flatten:
dt <- as.data.table(unlist(xmlToList(x)), keep.rownames=T)
setnames(dt, c("column", "value"))

## Add row numbers, but they're incorrect due to missing XML elements:
dt[, row:=.SD[,.I], by=column][]
          column      value row
1: parent.child1     ABC123   1
2: parent.child2 1381956044   1
3: parent.child2 1397527137   2
4: parent.child3       4675   1
5: parent.child1     DEF456   2
6: parent.child3       3735   2
7: parent.child3       3735   3

## Reshape from long to wide, but some value are in the wrong row:
dcast.data.table(dt, row~column, value.var="value", fill=NA)
##    row parent.child1 parent.child2 parent.child3
## 1:   1        ABC123    1381956044          4675
## 2:   2        DEF456    1397527137          3735
## 3:   3            NA            NA          3735
```

I won't know ahead of time the names of the child elements, or the count of unique element names for children of the grandparent, so the answer should be flexible.

### Updated example

The actual XML files have several layers of nesting, and I'm getting an error when using `xmlToDataFrame`.  Here is an updated (but still simplified) version:

```
x2 <- '<grandparent><grandparentInfo junk="TRUE"><grandparent1>foo</grandparent1><grandparent1>bar</grandparent1></grandparentInfo><parent><child1>ABC123</child1><child2>1381956044</child2></parent><parent><child2>1397527137</child2></parent><parent><child3>4675</child3></parent><parent><child1>DEF456</child1><child3>3735</child3></parent><parent><child1/><child3>3735</child3></parent></grandparent>'

xmlToDataFrame(x2)
## Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c("foo",  : 
##   duplicate subscripts for columns
```

Comment: Isn't `xmlToDataFrame` the function you are looking for?

Comment: @sgibb - I think that's right.  I get OPs desired result with `xmlToDataFrame(x)`

Comment: Thanks @sgibb and @RichardScriven.  See the updated example, `x2`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can simply use `xmlToDataFrame` on `x`

```
> library(XML)
> y <- xmlToDataFrame(x)
> y[y == ""] <- NA
> y
#   child1     child2 child3
# 1 ABC123 1381956044   <NA>
# 2   <NA> 1397527137   <NA>
# 3   <NA>       <NA>   4675
# 4 DEF456       <NA>   3735
# 5   <NA>       <NA>   3735
```

And for a `data.table` result,

```
> library(data.table)
> data.table(y)
#    child1     child2 child3
# 1: ABC123 1381956044     NA
# 2:     NA 1397527137     NA
# 3:     NA         NA   4675
# 4: DEF456         NA   3735
# 5:     NA         NA   3735
```

You'll probably want to employ the `colClasses` argument to get the columns into the right classes for analysis.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven (and @sgibb before that).  You're right, this works on this simple example.  My actual XML files are more complicated.  I had tried `xmlToDataFrame` in one of my attempts, but got an error message like `duplicate subscripts for columns`.  I'll try to update my example.  I may need to post another question, as I think it may require walking down the tree to certain nodes and then using the `xmlToDataFrame` solution.

Answer (score 1):

While searching for the "duplicate subscripts for columns" error mentioned in the comment to @RichardScriven, I found a related question: [Import Infopath .XML forms into data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593301/import-infopath-xml-forms-into-data-frame-in-r).  Borrowing from that, I modified my original attempt to get this solution:

```
## Convert XML to list
xl <- xmlToList(x2)
#xl[sapply(xl, is.null)] <- NA

## Function that splits the XML path "key" on the last dot, to get the "table" and "column":
splitKey <- function(text) {
  ss <- strsplit(text, "[.]")[[1]]
  lss <- length(ss)
  ifelse(lss==1, out <- c(NA,text), out <- c(paste0(ss[-lss], collapse="."), ss[lss]))
  return(out)
}

## Put flattened list in a data.table, and add the table/column names for each key:
dt2 <- as.data.table(unlist(xl), keep.rownames=T)
setnames(dt2, c("key", "value"))
dt2[, c("table","column"):=as.list(splitKey(key)), by=key][]
##                              key      value                  table       column
##  1: grandparentInfo.grandparent1        foo        grandparentInfo grandparent1
##  2: grandparentInfo.grandparent1        bar        grandparentInfo grandparent1
##  3:  grandparentInfo..attrs.junk       TRUE grandparentInfo..attrs         junk
##  4:                parent.child1     ABC123                 parent       child1
##  5:                parent.child2 1381956044                 parent       child2
##  6:                parent.child2 1397527137                 parent       child2
##  7:                parent.child3       4675                 parent       child3
##  8:                parent.child1     DEF456                 parent       child1
##  9:                parent.child3       3735                 parent       child3
## 10:                parent.child3       3735                 parent       child3

## Get the number of elements within each "parent" section
##  (this is the part I was missing in my original attempts):
newRows <- as.data.table(sapply(xl, length), keep.rownames=T)[V1=="parent", V2]
newRows
## [1] 2 1 1 2 2

## Subset the "parent" table, and add the correct row numbers:
dt2[table=="parent", row:=rep(seq_along(newRows),times=newRows)]
## Warning message:
## In `[.data.table`(dt2, table == "parent", `:=`(row, rep(seq_along(newRows),  :
##   Supplied 8 items to be assigned to 7 items of column 'row' (1 unused)

## Need to fix this answer to include null elements, since the `unlist` command seems to strip them out...

## Reshape from long to wide:
dcast.data.table(dt2[table=="parent"], row~column, value.var="value", fill=NA)
##    row child1     child2 child3
## 1:   1 ABC123 1381956044     NA
## 2:   2     NA 1397527137     NA
## 3:   3     NA         NA   4675
## 4:   4 DEF456         NA   3735
## 5:   5     NA         NA   3735
```

It feels like the `xmlToDataFrame` approach would be better than this, but I need to understand how to subset the XML better in order to use it...